# (Godot) Botão para voltar para a última cena

Tags: gdscript

Bom dia pessoal, estou com uma dúvida no Godot para voltar a última cena.
Deve funcionar como o botão de "Continue" após pausar o jogo.

Possuo um menu de opções que é acessado quando o usuário clica no pause.
Agora preciso que ao clicar em um botão específico desse menu, ele volte para a última cena que estava.

/*O jogo funciona como um livro interativo, então não há necessidade de armazenar os dados de um personagem, por exemplo. Só basta voltar para a última cena/página.*/

Estou usando esse código aqui e não tem funcionado:

```
extends Button

var saved = null

func save_current_scene():
    saved = get_tree().get_current_scene()

func reload_last_saved():
    get_tree().set_current_scene(saved)
    
func _on_Button_Pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene(saved)
```

Já tentei encontrar outras formas na internet de fazer, mas sempre utilizam um Node e não um botão. Tentei fazer de forma manual alterando esses códigos mas ainda assim não obtive êxito.
Gostaria que alguém me informasse o que estou fazendo de errado.

Agradeço desde já,

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que parece, seu menu fica numa cena a parte. Neste caso, você precisa usar um *singleton* para armazenar a cena atual, antes de entrar na cena do menu. Desta forma, você teria uma referência para a qual voltar.

Algo assim:

```
extends Control

onready var current_scene: Node = get_tree().get_current_scene()

func _process(_delta: float) -> void:
    if current_scene != get_tree().get_current_scene():
        current_scene = get_tree().get_current_scene()
```

Neste exemplo que dei, você ainda precisa garantir que a própria cena do menu não seja incluída no "current_scene". Isto pode ser evitado de diversas maneiras, uma maneira relativamente simples que sugiro é, verificar se o nome da cena é igual/inclui algum valor:

```
var _current_scene = get_tree().get_current_scene()
if current_scene != _current_scene and _current_scene.get_name() != "menu":
    current_scene = _current_scene
```

Feito isto, no teu botão você pode fazer algo assim (assumindo que o nome do seu *singleton* seja "Globals"):

```
extends Button

func _on_Button_Pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene_to(Globals.current_scene)
```